# Protractor extract data from a repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Starting testing Angular JS application with protractor I would like to extract search results of my application.

To do so I need to iterate through a repeater "objects in objects" and extract the name coloumn :

I am using this code :

```
var result = element.all(by.repeater('object in objects').column('name'))

result.then(function(arr) {

 //Traverse the repeater and extract data

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {

    arr[i].getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log( text);
       console.log( arr.length);
    });
}
```

This code displays only the first 6 elements even when my serach result is far more the 6.

Output :

```
TSK(AGR020J)(000)(AGR020JN00)(000)
40

40
TSK(ASA700J)(000)(ASA700JU00)(000)
40

40
TSK(AGR060J)(000)(AGR060JN00)(000)
40

40
TSK(AGT001H)(000)(AGT001HS20)(000)
40

40
TSK(ANF010J)(000)(ANF010JU00)(000)
40

40
TSK(AGT001H)(000)(AGT001HN20)(000)
40

40


40

40
 ....
```

6 is the number of elements in the first row of my results, I dont' know why the search doese not include remaining rows?

And here is the HTML temlate :

```
<div id="jobHolder" class="thumbJobs" style="height: 326px; overflow: hidden;"                           tabindex="5027">
<div id="job_1" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat=
"object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
  <div id="job_1_viewerEye" class="viewerEye" ng-click=
  "viewerEye($event,$index+1, object)" ng-class="object.viewerEyeClass"></div>

  <div id="job_1_jobBigPicto" class="jobBigPicto transition_2_opa">
    <div id="job_1_jobsSmallPictos" class="jobsSmallPictos transition_2_opa">
      <div id="job_1_jobDown" class="jobDown transition_2_opa">
        <div id="job_1_jobHoverInfo" class="jobHoverInfo" ng-click=
        "hideJobHoverInfo($event,$index+1)" style="left: -100%; top: 272px;"></div>

        <div id="job_2" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)"
        ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
          <div id="job_2_viewerEye" class="viewerEye" ng-click=
          "viewerEye($event,$index+1, object)" ng-class="object.viewerEyeClass">
          </div>

          <div id="job_2_jobBigPicto" class="jobBigPicto transition_2_opa">
            <div id="job_2_jobsSmallPictos" class="jobsSmallPictos transition_2_opa">
              <div id="job_2_jobDown" class="jobDown transition_2_opa">
                <div id="job_2_jobHoverInfo" class="jobHoverInfo" ng-click=
                "hideJobHoverInfo($event,$index+1)" style="left: -100%; top: 272px;">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Sorry I think I have pasted the wrong HTML you can see it now after modification :
    ng-repeat= "object in objects"

Comment: Could you provide your HTML template ?

Comment: I didn't see the repeater in your html template.

Comment: I have edited my HTML code you can se the repeater now : ng-repeat=
"object in objects"