# Angular JS Protractor extract data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

using protractor I would like to extract some specific data from my Angular JS application.
The data I want to extract is embedded in a external div with id "jobHolder" inside this div I have several embedded divs each have an id "job_i". where i goes from 1 to n...

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="thumbJobs" id="jobHolder" style=
"height: 275px; overflow: hidden;" tabindex="5052">
    <div class="job ng-scope" id="job_1">
        <div class="viewerEye" id="job_1_viewerEye"></div>
        <div class="jobBigPicto transition_2_opa" id="job_1_jobBigPicto">
            <div class="jobsSmallPictos transition_2_opa" id=
            "job_1_jobsSmallPictos">
                <div class="jobDown transition_2_opa" id="job_1_jobDown">
                    <div class="jobTitle ng-binding">
                        TSK(Z87700J)(000)(Z87700JU00)(000)
                    </div>
                    <div class="jobText ng-binding"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="jobHoverInfo" id="job_1_jobHoverInfo"></div>
                <div class="job ng-scope" id="job_2">
                    <div class="job ng-scope" id="job_3">
                        <div class="job ng-scope" id="job_4">
                            <div class="job ng-scope" id="job_5">
                                <div class="job ng-scope" id="job_6">
                                    <div class="job ng-scope" id="job_7">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to extract is the jobTitle in each inernal DIV. I have tried with repeaters but i could not extract all data so I am trying to use Id instead.

I want to extract all data ambedded in a div having id = job_i where i goes from 1 to the last index of the last DIV with the same id?

I have used this code to extract the data but the code Displays only the first 6 elements.
Could it be a synchronisation ot time out issue?

```
 for (var i=1; i<20;i++)
    {
    var result =   ptor.findElement(by.xpath('html/body/div[2]/div[1]/section[5]/div[4]/div['+i+']/div[4]/div[1]'));

    result.getText().then(function(text)
    {
        console.log(text);
    });
```

And here is the console output it shows only 6 elements whereas the web page is displaying 20 elements :

```
TSK(Z87700J)(000)(Z87700JU00)(000)
TSK(AGD170JFZZ)(000)
TSK(ZA1112O)(000)(ZA1111OU00)(000)
TSK(ZA1100O)(000)(ZA1100OU00)(000)
TSK(ZA1111O)(000)(ZA1111OU00)(000)
WAR27_STEP16 A TASK FOR CHAR FR
AN TASK WITH SPACE
WAR81_STEP_NETWORK_SESSION_MU
TSK(TTS758J)(000)(TTS758JN00)(000)
.

Finished in 10.851 seconds
1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
```

Comment: do you know how may internal divs are there i.e the value of n ?

Comment: can you not use a for loop and then recursively go till bottom to get all the data ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protractor extract data from a repeater](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557551/protractor-extract-data-from-a-repeater)

Comment: It's the same problem but I am trying to handle through xpath here instead of repeater.

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting a timing issue since by default all findElement requests are asynchronous in nature and return a Promise. You might be better off writing your code as follows:

```
     for (var i=1; i<20;i++)
        {
    ptor.findElement(by.xpath('html/body/div[2]/div[1]/section[5]/div[4]/div['+i+']/div[4]/div[1]'))
        .then(function(result){
            result.getText().then(function(text)
            {
                console.log(text);
            });
        });
```

This should wrap each one of the findElement requests so that they each get handled properly after the promise resolves.

Another thing you might look at is using findElements to get back an array that you then iterate and dump to the console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code shows also only the 6 first items, in fact i have tried to displayed the 7th, 8th... items using xpath but It did noy work neither, protractor is not able to see/find thoses elements even though they are well displayed in the screen which is very strange!!!